# Avoiding Helper Functions for Doing Comparisons

Tags: c++, stl, comparison

Say I have a type with a member function:

```
class Thing {
    std::string m_name;
public:
    std::string & getName() {
        return m_name;
    }
};
```

And say I have a collection of that type:

```
std::vector<Thing> things;
```

And I want to keep the things in order by name. To do that, I use std::lower_bound to figure out where to put it:

```
bool thingLessThan(Thing const& thing, std::string const& name) {
    return thing.getName() < name;
}

void addThing(std::string const& name) {
    vector<Thing>::iterator position = lower_bound(
        things.begin(), things.end(),
        name,
       thingLessThan);
    if (position == things.end() || position->getName() != name) {
        position = things.insert(position, Thing());
        position->getName() = name;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do the same thing as the `thingLessThan` function without actually creating a function, perhaps using std::mem_fun, std::less, etc?

Comment: You could use a lambda. It's inlined right into the function call. You could also use a container that automatically orders its elements, but you'll need to define `operator<` for it to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Other than a lambda you can simply define an `operator<` which adheres to strict weak ordering to allow a container of your object to be comparable by STL algorithms with the default predicate `std::less`

```
class whatever
{
public:
   bool operator<(const whatever& rhs) const { return x < rhs.x; }

private:
   int x;
};

std::vector<whatever> v;
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
```

Comment: I suppose this is the best we can do prior to C++11. I can't wait until g++ is officially 100% C++11 compatible. I'm really hurting for some move semantics and lambdas.

Comment: @TravisParks You don't need g++ to support 100% of C++11. It doesn't even support all of C++-98. But it already supports both move semantics and lambdas. So whatever is holding you back, it's not G++. :)

Comment: I just don't want to specify anything in the command line. I'll wait until everything is turned on by default.

Answer (score 2):

Sure. You can use a lambda expression (assuming your compiler supports it):

```
vector<Thing>::iterator position = lower_bound(
    things.begin(), things.end(),
    name,
   [](Thing const& thing, std::string const& name) { return thing.getName() < name; });
```

Of course, an alternative option is just to define `operator<` for the class, then it will be used by default, if you don't specify another comparer function for `std::lower_bound`.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what your purpose is? If you just like the syntactic niceness of not declaring something to be used in one place, use lambda expressions to create an anonymous function.

Answer (score 0):

You can overload `operator<()` and use `std::less<T>` if you don't want to write predicates contantly. Also you can use lambda-expressions, which would be much nicer, because `operator<()` is logically connected only with things, that can be put in some order in obvious ways, like numbers or strings.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a std::map, the strings will be placed in alphabetical order automatically.  If you want to modify the ordering further, create your own key comparison function.  I think this would be the simplest option.

To use a std::list, you can write your own comparison code inside of the addThing() function that goes through the list looking at each string and inserts the new one at the appropriate place.